# Take picture in android fails

Tags: java, android

I went over all the related posts and no answer was found.
I'm trying to take a picture with the Camera library and it fails on take picture method. 
What the code is suppose to do, is when pressed a button to show an image over the ImageView (simple as this sounds).
The app crashes when it gets to take picture, stack trace attached at end.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.drivesafe.drivesafe;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import java.util.Timer;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static ProgressDialog detectionProgressDialog;
    public static ImageView imageView;
    public static Camera camera;
    public static Camera.PictureCallback pictureCallback;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                take_picture();
            }

        });
        this.detectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        this.pictureCallback = new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext());
        this.initFrontCamera();
    }
    private void take_picture() {
        camera.startPreview();
        camera.takePicture(null, null, null, this.pictureCallback);
    }

    private void initFrontCamera() {
        camera = Camera.open(1); //front camera
    }

}
```

**PhotoHandler.java**

```
package com.drivesafe.drivesafe;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PhotoHandler implements PictureCallback  {
    private final Context context;

    public PhotoHandler(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        MainActivity.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.drivesafe.drivesafe, PID: 28460
              java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
                  at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
                  at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1545)
                  at com.drivesafe.drivesafe.MainActivity.take_picture(MainActivity.java:43)
                  at com.drivesafe.drivesafe.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:13)
                  at com.drivesafe.drivesafe.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:29)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
   Application terminated.
```

Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />
```

I would love some help please.

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "it fails on take picture method" means. For example, are you crashing? If so, what does LogCat show in terms of a Java stack trace?

Comment: application crashes, added stack trace

Comment: You are not configuring the `Camera` at all, and perhaps on your device the defaults have issues. You are also blindly using `open(1)`, not paying any attention to whether that camera exists or is the one that you want (1 is not magically a front-facing camera). Overall, I recommend that you use a third-party library, like CameraKit-Android or Fotoapparat, to work with the camera APIs.

Comment: I understand what you're saying and I will change it, but when debugging I see that the camera is initialized properly.

Comment: "but when debugging I see that the camera is initialized properly" -- you cannot see, from a debugger, if a `Camera` is initialized properly, simply because all of the initialization code is outside of your app and its process.